# webview crashes when i click links

Tags: android, android-webview

I have this android app im working on that converts a website to an APP. basically using a webview. i have everything working thus far. the only thing is that if i click inside the app , when i click links for the website it crashes. and i have no idea why. If i press a link to buy something , i get a application has stopped error and it crashes.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


        //init the webview
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        //grab web settings
        WebSettings webSettings= webView.getSettings();
        //get web settings
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //load your url
        webView.loadUrl("https://gvsportscards.com/");
        //for opening links inside app
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                webView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/user/GVSportsCards/featured");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){

        if (webView.canGoBack()){

            webView.goBack();


        }else {

            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.play) {

            webView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCDOjqC1rwUVd-qQ9ThOTuNA/live");
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

the end goal is ofcourse to be able to use the full functionality of the site on the app. almost there!

here is there error log

```
 02-19 02:26:40.009 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv D/ViewRootImpl@4e22ff4[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
02-19 02:26:40.066 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv D/ViewRootImpl@4e22ff4[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
02-19 02:26:43.777 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(23)] "JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 1.4.1", source: https://gvsportscards.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1 (23)
02-19 02:26:44.360 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "YT API ready", source: https://gvsportscards.com/wp-content/plugins/youtube-embed-plus/scripts/ytprefs.min.js?ver=5.0.3 (5)
02-19 02:26:44.604 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "[object Object]", source: https://gvsportscards.com/wp-content/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/assets/js/angelleye-in-context-checkout.min.js?ver=1550572004 (1)
02-19 02:26:44.607 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(45)] "JQMIGRATE: 'hover' pseudo-event is deprecated, use 'mouseenter mouseleave'", source: https://gvsportscards.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1 (45)
02-19 02:26:44.608 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(47)] "console.trace", source: https://gvsportscards.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1 (47)
02-19 02:26:44.653 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(45)] "JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated", source: https://gvsportscards.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1 (45)
02-19 02:26:44.653 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(47)] "console.trace", source: https://gvsportscards.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1 (47)
02-19 02:26:44.763 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(45)] "JQMIGRATE: 'ready' event is deprecated", source: https://gvsportscards.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1 (45)
02-19 02:26:44.764 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(47)] "console.trace", source: https://gvsportscards.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1 (47)
02-19 02:26:45.503 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv D/ViewRootImpl@4e22ff4[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
02-19 02:26:46.647 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv D/ViewRootImpl@4e22ff4[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
02-19 02:26:47.124 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv D/ViewRootImpl@4e22ff4[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
02-19 02:26:47.197 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv D/ViewRootImpl@4e22ff4[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
02-19 02:26:47.280 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv W/ResourceType: Invalid package identifier when getting bag for resource number 0x0213014a
02-19 02:26:47.367 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv D/ScrollView: initGoToTop
02-19 02:26:47.394 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv D/ScrollView: initGoToTop
02-19 02:26:47.469 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv D/ViewRootImpl@91ddf36[MainActivity]: setView = DecorView@57eae37[] TM=true MM=false
02-19 02:26:47.517 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv D/ViewRootImpl@91ddf36[MainActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
02-19 02:26:47.520 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
02-19 02:26:47.521 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-19 02:26:47.540 7028-7028/com.example.michael.webappgv E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.michael.webappgv, PID: 7028
                                                                            android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
                                                                                at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:216)
                                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2148)
                                                                                at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1157)
                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:421)
                                                                                at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:416)
                                                                                at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:407)
                                                                                at org.chromium.content.browser.input.SelectPopupAdapter.getView(SelectPopupAdapter.java:13)
                                                                                at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:3189)
                                                                                at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1448)
                                                                                at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1355)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23297)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23297)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23297)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.widget.AlertDialogLayout.tryOnMeasure(AlertDialogLayout.java:144)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.widget.AlertDialogLayout.onMeasure(AlertDialogLayout.java:69)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23297)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23297)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23297)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6928)
                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:899)
                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23297)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2881)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1884)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2166)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1780)
                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7827)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

actiity main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.michael.webappgv.MainActivity">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#3d3a3a"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button">

    </WebView>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="YouTube"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:background="#050505"
        android:textColor="#c70808"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: *`application has stopped error and it crashes.`* have u check the logcat fro error, if not than check and share crash log with question

Comment: show us crash report or log

Comment: @sushantgosavi added the log

Comment: Can you put the XML layout file for webview.?
set width and height to match parent and check it

Comment: show us your layout primary assumption is your activity_main  didn't contain webView id

Comment: @sushantgosavi added my activity main

Comment: Did you try with remove app build directory then -> Invalidate cache/Restart and then -> clean , build project ??

Comment: @sushantgosavi trying it now , but i dont see how that will help lol

Comment: @sushantgosavi i did what you asked , it did nothing =(    . to be more  clearer . when i open the app , it loads the website. everything works , but when i click the buy option on the website , it  crashes. its weird , i can click all other buttons on the website and it works fine , but when i click the  drop down box that lists teams to buy on the website. it crashes.

Comment: use custom WebViewClient and override onReciveError and onReciveHTTPError and print long and show us

Comment: Can you try after adding this in web view
mWebView.setFocusable(true);
mWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
Hope This Works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use custom webviewclient

```
public class LoginWebClient extends WebViewClient {


  @Override
  public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
    super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
  }

  @Override
  public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request,
      WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
    super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
  }
}
```

pritnt log and show us

Comment: Let me know the device you testing ? is it Oreo ?

Comment: Try to update your compileSdkVersion to 26, and update your com.android.support:appcompat-v7 to 26    and let me know

Comment: yes, after hours of convincing myself it wasnt my code , i uninstalled anddrio studio and updated everything. and it now finally works. thank you